# navigating to sub folder

Tags: javascript, asp.net, navigation

i need to redirect on page load to to sub folder aspx page from index.html page. i m using following code and getting error.

```
window.location.href = 'URL= HMIS/Login.aspx'</script>
```

Error

```
resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /URL= /HMIS/Login.aspx
```

Comment: can you share some insights into the folder structure you're using? where is your index.aspx and how is it related to /HMIS/Login.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
top.location='HMIS/Login.aspx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: window.location.href = 'HMIS/Login.aspx'?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
window.location.href = 'URL= ../HMIS/Login.aspx'

instead of:
window.location.href = 'URL= HMIS/Login.aspx'

if you are using javascript then use ..(double dot) like ~ in asp.